# VS Code showing eslint error but vitest is working. 'vi' is not defined

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vitest

I have the following `tsconfig` configuration:

```json
{
  "include": ["tests/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "lib": [],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  }
}
```

As I have defined types for vitest/globals so `yarn vitest` cmd is working fine and executing the tests cases as well.

But in VS Code its showing me the following error:

[image: vi is not defined]

How I can fix or silence this issue in vs-code?

Answer (score 16):

I had to add the following to my `.eslintrc.json` file to fix this issue in  a test setup module:

```json
"globals": {
  "vi": true
},
```

If you're using TypeScript, you should also add the following to your `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`. (You already had this, but I'm mentioning it anyway in case it helps someone else):

```json
"types": ["vitest/globals"]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this problem was to increase the ecmaVersion in the `.eslintrc.js` file from `2020` to `2022` like this:

```json
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2022,
}
```

Since you are using TypeScript, you could also try setting the target to 2022 like this:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2022"
}
```